# How to make Multi-Pane GUI in WPF or C#?

Tags: c#, forms, panel

I have seen this user interface in some screen shots of some RSS Readers.  It is a multi-pane user interface.  THere are three panels or "panes" to the window, in other words, the window is divided into three parts and the user is able to mouse over the division and click on the seperation bar and resize the section.

How is this sort of GUI developed in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinForms, this is done with a [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx). The [Orientation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.orientation(v=VS.100).aspx) property can be used to get vertical or horizontal splits. You can also nest splitcontainers to get multiple splits.

In WPF there is no SplitContainer, but the same effect can be achieved with a [Grid and a GridSplitter](http://learnwpf.com/Posts/Post.aspx?postId=fbd8e1ed-dbd4-45c1-9b9c-a8355679f196).

Finally, note that "WPF or C#" is a false dichotomy. WPF and WinForms are just UI frameworks in the .NET framework. Both can be used with any .NET language, including C#, VB.NET, etcetera.

Comment: OK, so we have a grid and a girdsplitter in WPF.  How do they work?  I assmume that a "Grid" is the overall playing field and the gridsplitter is what splits it apart.  Is that right?  Does it split it apart by bing the line dividing the grid or is "GridSplitter" the panels inside the grid?

Comment: @xarzu: the GridSplitter is just an element inside a Grid. It makes use of the fact that an element in a grid can span multiple rows or columns. Other than that the only special thing about is that dragging it changes the size of the neighbouring rows or columns.