# Are Visio-Like WPF GUI's possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visio

I want to create buttons and displays in WPF that look something like the Visio Flow Chart displays.  Are there classes for that?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776700/limits-of-guis-in-c posted by same user. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776713/how-to-make-multi-pane-gui-in-wpf-or-c and several others.

Comment: @Neil: Doesn't look like a dupe to me. Those other questions don't mention Visio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a series of articles which show you how to create a drag'n'drop flow chart designer in WPF:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The problem with that particular implementation (WPF Diagram Designer on Code Project) is that it is not MVVM based and generally doesn't use an architecture that is flexible or extensible to further development (e.g. just wanting to add Undo/Redo support would argue for a rewrite). It does, however, include a path finding algorithm (though in production use I fear it may be a little buggy).

I would recommend looking at the WpfDesigner.* assemblies in the SharpDevelop project (it's open source) and the WPF DrawTools on Code Project (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22776/WPF-DrawTools). The architectures of both of these are at least somewhat amenable to further development. Just ensure the licensing is compatible with your use, particularly for SharpDevelop.

Answer (score 0):

I found http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182683/NetworkView-A-WPF-custom-control-for-visualizing-a quite good. You would need to extend it with some UI templates to get the shapes you want and perhaps change the connector attachment scheme to fixed locations.